# Skip Empty Cells in a Range Function without loop with VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a combobox and I want to add a element that are defined in different sheet, so I used.

```
cmbType.List = Sheets("TBL_USER_META").Range("B3:B6").Value
```

Now my problems are:

1. This range can increase in future, so can we select whole B column?
2. Currently, range also includes the blank cell, that is visible in
       combobox. Can we skip those?

I have found various solutions to skip blank cell, but all other solution use loop to iterate each cell and check if it's blank or not.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your source range will not grow over some 65536 cells and their content doesn't have any blank character, you could use:

```
With Sheets("TBL_USER_META")
    cmbType.List = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value), " ")), " ")
End With
```

should they have any blank character, you'd need some more twicking

Comment: Thanks @DisplayName :-) If you have a time can you please eloborate how it's work?

Comment: You are welcome. As to how it works: 1) `.Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))` references the range in column 2 from row 3 down to last not empty cell 2)  the `.Value` of a 1D "columned" range returns a 2D nx1 sized `Variant` array 3) `Application.Transpose()` trasnposes the 2D nx1-sized array into a 1D n-sized one 4) `Join()` joins all items of a 1D array into a `String`, with the wanted delimeter (`" "`) 5) `WorksheetFunction.Trim()` collapses adjacent multiple occurrences of " " into a single `" "` 6) `Split()` returns a 1D n-sized array out of a string, given a delimeter (`" "`)